# viewWillTransitionToSize safeArea and presentViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation

On rotation of the screen, I need to do some recalculation of internal views.
I have a UIViewController and UIScrollView embedded there. The internal views depend on the size of the ScrollView frame.

So in the UIViewController I have following code:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
DDLogDebug(@">>>>>>>>>>>>> %@", NSStringFromCGSize(size));
[super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

[coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
    DDLogDebug(@"+++++++++ mainScroll %@", NSStringFromCGRect(_mainScroll.frame));
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    self.view.frame = newFrame;
    [self.view.layer layoutIfNeeded];
    DDLogDebug(@"--------- mainScroll %@", NSStringFromCGRect(_mainScroll.frame));

    // and update the children

}
completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
}];
}
```

So far so good. I see that after setting by hand size of the frame to the controller's view and calling layoutIfNeeded (or layoutSubviews - same results), the mainScroll size is properly adjusted including consideration of safeArea constraints and everything is fine.

Now, somewhere in the code there is a popup controller called

```
[self presentViewController:controllerToPresent animated:NO completion:nil];
```

nothing is interesting, but this presented controller goes on top of the other one, I described above, and mainScroll is in the background too.
Now, attempt to rotate screen leads to situation that size of mainScroll after layoutIfNeeded is 20 points taller, than it was without popup controller. It seems, like safeArea guides/constraints are not applied in background. After closing the popup controller, the mainScroll is bigger than expected and I have mislpaced views...
Any hints?

Why "presentViewController" affects behaviour of the caller in respect of viewWillTransitionToSize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to address the challenge I came to following solution:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
        [self updateLayoutAfterRotation:size];
    }
    completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
    }];
}

- (void)viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange {
    [super viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange];
    [self updateLayoutAfterRotation:self.view.frame.size];
}

- (void)updateLayoutAfterRotation:(CGSize)size {
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    self.view.frame = newFrame;
    [self.view.layer layoutIfNeeded];

    // Here is custom code to adopt layout
}
```

Interesting to observe, that when this viewController is rotated on its own (top view on the screen), first you receive `viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange`, and then `viewWillTransitionToSize`.
But if the controller's view was hidden behind pop-up controller, it will be opposite order of calls. `viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange` is called first, when the pop-up controller is closed (i.e. not anymore at time when rotation of the screen happening)